# Hi, I like this girl, I wanna marry her but im young (im a teenager)

Tags: halal-haram

As i said in the title, I like this girl. She likes me too. We talk but theres no touching involved, no haram stuff talked about and I cant marry her now because, nobody would allow a teenager to get married to another teenager right?

so im just wondering, is this haram or halal?

Comment: We are not  peer support group. Nikah is halal regardless of age and would make permissible talking, touching or whatever else. Anything without Nikah is not halal.